# Is it possible to hide/invisible notebook page based on states? (Odoo 13)

Tags: state, odoo, odoo-13, one2many

I have the notebook page and 4 states in the form view.

I want the notebook page just to show in states 1 and 2 when clicking the wizard button. But when it changes to states 3 and 4, it will be hide/invisible.
So is it possible to do it?

Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ***invisible attributes*** for the page.

```
<page string="Product Details" attrs="{'invisible':[('state', 'in', [2, 4])]}">
...
</page>
```

If state in [2, 4] is true, then the page will be invisible.

For more details, read [reference](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/hiding-a-page-depends-on-condition-114362)

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thank you, Khay Leang.